# How to calculate traveled distance with non constant acceleration in time?

Tags: acceleration, velocity, distance

I know this formula *D = v*t + 1/2*a*t^2* for calculating the distance given initial velocity, time and acceleration. But what if my acceleration is not static, but increasing exponentially defined by f(n) = *a^n*? If the acceleration *a* starts increasing at distance *x* and time *tx* (reference point a) and I do a measurement after *n* seconds (reference point b) with the formula above, the results would be incorrect, because the acceleration initially was smaller.

Example: at reference point *a* object travels at velocity 10 m/s and acceleration is *2 m/s^2* and time is 40 seconds (*tx*). After this point acceleration starts to increase by *a(n) = a^n* where n is every second after tx. So at *n=2* (total 42 seconds) seconds acceleration would be *4 m/s^2*, *n=3* it would be *8 m/s^2* and so on. I want to measure the distance from *a* to *b*, where *b* is after *n=10* (total 50 seconds).

Example2: at reference point *a* object travels at velocity 10 m/s and acceleration is *2 m/s^2* and time is 40 seconds (tx). After this point acceleration starts to increase by *a(n) = a^dn* where *dn* is every meter after *a*. So at *dn=2* (total a+2 meters) seconds acceleration would be *4 m/s^2*, *dn=3* it would be *8 m/s^2* and so on. I want to measure the distance from *a* to *b*, where *b* is after after 10 seconds (total 50 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Use calculus:
$$v(t)\equiv\int a(t)\ dt$$
and
$$x(t)\equiv\int v(t)\ dt.$$

---

update:

First try some special cases:

- $a(t)=(0{\rm\ m/s^2})$
- $a(t)=a_0$ (where $a_0$ is a constant)
- $a(t)=j_0 t$
- $a(t)=A\sin(\omega t)$

---

(By the way, "acceleration is not static, but increasing exponentially" as "$f(n) = a^n$" doesn't make sense to me.)

---

example: With $a(t)=j_0 t$,
then
$v(t)=\frac{1}{2}j_0 t^2 + v_0$
and
$x(t)=\frac{1}{6}j_0 t^3 +v_0 t+x_0$.

---

Update2

You need to write down an acceleration function as a possibly piecewise function of t. ( Draw a graph of $a(t)$. )

Once you have that function, use the formula to get the velocity and then the next formula to get the position.

Comment: Can you please put it in a example?

Comment: As passed the distance x, every next second n the acceleration increases by a^n. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @JohnT No, it doesn't. $a(t)$ depends on $t$. Do you possibly mean $a(t)=Kt^n$, where $K$ and $n$ are constants (where $K$ has units of ($\rm\ m/s^2)/(s^n)$)?

Comment: @JohnT Maybe you mean $a(t)=A\exp(kt)$ where $A$ has units of $\rm m/s^2$ and $k$ has units of $\rm 1/s$.

Comment: I updated the question with precise example.

Comment: Tuned it a bit, sorr

Comment: @JohnT I updated the answer with a strategy. I’ll let you work out the details.

Comment: I think your strategy introduces the same problem I am trying to address here. If I calculate acceleration at point b and use it to calculate the distance (a to b), the results will be invalid as it assuming that acceleration was same for entire distance (like 2 m/s^2), but its not. It was exponentially growing (2 m/s^2, 4 m/s^2, 8 m/s^2...).

Comment: The current velocity (at point b) that is reached by acceleration on its own can not describe the distance traveled in time. That's why we have `D = vt + 1/2at^2` this formula. But a is a constant here (assumed to be same for whole t).

Comment: Ouh I think I got your point. Crawling in to my dungeons and doing some math :D